Issue with Thread Synchronization Using Semaphores (Printing Sequence)
Question:
I'm working on a C program where I have two threads, p1 and p2, and I need them to print the sequence 1234 1234 1234 .... I am using semaphores to synchronize the threads, but the output is not as expected.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t s1, s2;

void *p1(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        printf("1");
        sem_post(&s1);
    
        sem_wait(&s2);
        printf("3");
        sem_post(&s1);
        }
    return NULL;
    }

void *p2(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&s1);
        printf("2");
        sem_post(&s2);
    
        sem_wait(&s1);
        printf("4 ");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    sem_init(&s1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&s2, 0, 0);

    pthread_t t1, t2;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, p1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, p2, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&s1);
    sem_destroy(&s2);

    return 0;
}

The output is: 12314 2314 2314 ... instead of the expected 1234 1234 1234 .... Can someone help me fix the semaphore synchronization to get the correct output?

I think you need a sem_wait(&s2); at the top of the loop in p1() and a sem_post(&s2); at the bottom of the loop in p2(), which restores symmetry to the code.  You need to initialize s2 so that p1() can wait successfully on the first iteration.

printf("3"); --> sem_post(&s1); --> printf("1"); Fix this sequence.

You don't wait for 4 to be printed before printing 1.
The following is a fixed version. See comments for the three relevant changes.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t s1, s2;

void *p1(void *arg) {
    (void)arg;  // Silence "unused" warning.

    for (int i=10; i--; ) {
        sem_wait(&s2);     // This was missing.
        printf("1");
        sem_post(&s1);
    
        sem_wait(&s2);
        printf("3");
        sem_post(&s1);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *p2(void *arg) {
    (void)arg;  // Silence "unused" warning.

    for (int i=10; i--; ) {
        sem_wait(&s1);
        printf("2");
        sem_post(&s2);
    
        sem_wait(&s1);
        printf("4 ");
        sem_post(&s2);     // This was missing.
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    sem_init(&s1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&s2, 0, 1);   // This wasn't initialized correctly.

    pthread_t t1, t2;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, p1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, p2, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&s1);
    sem_destroy(&s2);

    return 0;
}

Demo on Compiler Explorer
